# Need to wait until XMLHttpRequest completes

Tags: javascript, xui

Whenever I try to find answer of this question everyone refers to ajax start/stop etc.

I am using [XUI JS's XHR](http://xuijs.com/docs/xhr) function for cross domain calling, now I want exactly like this

```
callMyXHRfunction();
callNextFunctionWhenAboveFunctionResponded();
```

i.e. I should move forward until unless my xhr function responds (either success or failure)

**Update**

Use Case:

There is a function called getAllData(), this function get all my current data submitted to server. I need to call this function often to get the latest data and move ahead. While loggin I call this function to get latest data and after every 10 mins I need to call this to get data refreshed.

So if I call each my function on success function then my code may confuse other developer and if I write like above he/she will easily know what is going on in first line and in 2nd line.

Hope now everyone understand my situation very well.

Answer (score 1):

See third example on the website you are referencing:

```
x$( selector ).xhr( url, fn );
```

Second argument can be a callback, callback being the keyword you were probably looking for to begin with.

Alternatively, use a synchronous call by supplying `async: false` as an option.

```
x$("body").xhr("http://the-url",{ async: false });
```

Control flow will pause until the request returned and only then continue with your next function. See http://jsfiddle.net/ZQ9uw/ for reference.

Comment: yes, in that case I need to call callNextFunctionWhenAboveFunctionResponded() in the callback function, I dont want that as I need to call callMyXHRfunction() in many cases and for each callback there is a different action, hope you get my point

Comment: I actually don't get that. If you have to respond to each cross domain call with a different function being executed on success, then there's no way around specifying a separate function to be called for each successful XHR call. Maybe it would be helpful to see more contents of your two call*() functions so we'd understand your problem better.

Comment: Added a use case, please check and let me know if you still have any doubt

Comment: Ravi, disabling async execution will do exactly what you need, you just need to apply it to your code so I'd say your question is answered. That aside, I absolutely concur with @Jon that this is bad practice especially for your use case which is refreshing data and you should absolutely encourage your team to become better programmers if event driven programming like that throws them off. Regardless, if you can't fix your process, not using async is your answer.

Comment: So as per you and Jon I should use all functions in callBack function, otherwise I have do disable the async, yes? but I cannot disable(due to requirement) this as this is just an example and I am having lots of scenarios like this. I want functionality like jQuery When(http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/) functionality.

Comment: You realize that jQuery When is also just attaching a callback to an event, namely, the request finishing? What your syntax above implies is that you have an xhr request and that you need to call the next function once it finishes, that's EXACTLY what a callback is. Familiarize yourself with these concepts, I think you can not be helped any further.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17394/discussion-between-henrik-and-ravi)

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the `.xhr` call in a way that specifies a callback function and pass in your "next" function as the callback.

So you'd write it like this:

```
callMyXHRFunction(nextFunctionToCall); // no parens after nextFunctionToCall!

function callMyXHRFunction(callback) {
    $("something").xhr(url, {
        error: callback, // so that nextFunctionToCall is called on error
        callback: callback, // so that nextFunctionToCall is called on success
        async: true
        // add more options here
    });
}
```

Comment: yes, right now I am doing in this way only, passing parameters and manipulating etc., is there any way I can do exactly like I mention above, I just want to wait until there is any response and then move, not like moving the flow to the other direction

Comment: What you might be looking for then is a synchronous call. I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: @Ravi: There is, but IMO it's very bad practice and I wouldn't be caught dead writing code like that.

Comment: @Jon: but IMO this is the best approach as my team mate may get confused if he/she see many condition in one function, I updated my answer and added a use case, please let me know if this help